# Get Video Details From Vimeo iOS SDK Once Uploaded?

Tags: ios, swift, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-ios

I have used [VimeoUpload](https://github.com/vimeo/VimeoUpload) SDK in My App to upload videos and its working fine.

During Development I noticed that the SDK created upload URL has a `video_file_id` and it does not match with the `video_id` once upload is completed.

SDK generated URL :

> https://1511928471.cloud.vimeo.com/upload?ticket_id=59821e7edc5840322fc360b63d9414c7_45995664&video_file_id=520623428&signature=ec0ce3b5852802957cc1e19c2cccbfa8&v6=1

How can I get the video details of last uploaded video in Vimeo?

Comment: Hi i tried to implement uploading but its not giving uploading status and uploaded URL in call back, could you please share your uploading code ?

Answer (score 1):

Great question, from the reply to the [Github issue you filed](https://github.com/vimeo/VimeoUpload/issues/84):

You can get the video object associated with the file you just uploaded in three ways:

1. The video object is returned in the "activate" response. This request is made by the `OldUploadDescriptor` as soon as the file upload completes. Check out the `.Activate` case [here](https://github.com/vimeo/VimeoUpload/blob/v0.9/VimeoUpload/Upload/Descriptor%20System/Old%20Upload/OldUploadDescriptor.swift#L227). Actually, now that I'm writing this, the video object might actually come back in the `.Settings` response. Either way the example of how to do this is at the same link above.
2. You can also request a video object separately from anything related to the upload flow by making a `GET` request to the video's uri. The `VideoOperation` class contains an [example of this](https://github.com/vimeo/VimeoUpload/blob/v0.9/VimeoUpload/Upload/Operations/Async/VideoOperation.swift).
3. You can also access the `video.uri` and entire video object on the descriptor itself (once the upload is complete). Look [here](https://github.com/vimeo/VimeoUpload/blob/v0.9/VimeoUpload/Upload/Descriptor%20System/Old%20Upload/OldUploadDescriptor.swift#L38).

Let us know if you have other questions (I'm an author of the library).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is worked correctly.
I can get the video url at .Settings case after upload the video.
In the .Activate case,
 I could only get like https://1511928471.cloud.vimeo.com/upload?ticket_id=59821e7edc5840322fc360b63d9414c7_45995664&video_file_id=520623428&signature=ec0ce3b5852802957cc1e19c2cccbfa8&v6=1.

but in the .Settings case,
I could get videoUrl

Thanks, Alfie Hanssen.